# When drawing a vector on paper, does it matter where I'm putting the arrow?

Tags: vectors, notation

[image]

Let a vector $\vec{P}$ passes along the line segment $AB$. Now, from the figure, can we say that $|\vec{P}|=AD$? [*$D$ is the point where I drew the arrow*]

In other words, when drawing a vector on paper, does it matter where I'm putting the arrow, or is the arrow's sole purpose just to indicate direction?

Comment: You should use whatever notation you think you're going to understand when you come back and look at it later.  This advice applies to more than just vectors.

Comment: To avoid confusion, you could put a dot at point D (as well as the head of the vector),, which will clearly show that vector P ends at point D.

Comment: Related: [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4405256/768162), [2](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/699314/260477)

Comment: @tryingtobeastoic One important fact is that vectors aren't physical objects. They are mathematical ones. Any set of objects that obey the axioms of a [vector space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space) are vectors. Of course, Euclidean space is the vector space familiar to everyone. Functions can be vectors too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In other words, when drawing a vector on paper, does it matter where I'm putting the arrow, or is the arrow's sole purpose just to indicate direction?

Arrow is usually placed at the end of the line that represents a vector and indicates vector direction.

> Let a vector $\vec{P}$ passes along the line segment $AB$. Now, from the figure, can we say that $|\vec{P}|=AD$?

I do not see from your schematic how is vector $\vec{P}$ related to the line that passes through points $A$ and $B$. I would conclude that $\vec{P} = \vec{AD}$.

Answer (score 0):

Vectors are usually thought of as existing at a point in space.  For example the electric field vector.  But as long as you don't change the direction or magnitude, you can translate a vector anywhere.  For example, for the purpose of making the addition or subtraction with another vector more visual.

Of course, if you are going to translate a vector to perform, for example, an addition, **it does matter** where you place the vector.  You must place the tail of it at the end of the vector you are adding it to.

For subtraction, you should place both vectors tails together.