# Is my book drawing a vector wrongly?

Tags: vectors, conventions, notation

**My book's drawing:**

[image]

According to my book, $\underline{u}=\vec{AB}$. However, my book hasn't put the arrow at the end of the line segment $AB$, but rather my book has put the arrow at the middle of $AB$. According to this [answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/699236/260477),

> Arrow is usually placed at the end of the line that represents a vector and indicates vector direction.

So, isn't my book's figure wrong?

Comment: Crossposted to https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4405256/11127

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The position of the arrow head usually doesn't matter. It's more of a convention to put it at the end of the line.